# ORA-00972: identifier is too long error with EF Core 2.2 code first migration

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, ef-code-first, database-migration

I am using code first migration with EF core 2.2 and I am able to create migration file through create command but when using the Database update command it is throwing above error(ORA-00972: identifier is too long). I have checked online and found that oracle has 30 Char limit and my all table names are less than 30 char. After analysis i found that problem is being created when foreign key relation names are being created automatically and have length more that 30 chars.

So my question is , do we have a otpion to trim down these automatically created DB relation names to 30 chars with the help of modelbuilder ?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I found the solution for it at the oracle site and it is as below :

// Limit 30 char length as per Oracle

modelBuilder.Model.Relational().MaxIdentifierLength = 30;

All you need to do write this code where you are building model and it will trimmed down all your automatically created relation in to 30 chars. It will keep uniqueness in case of duplicity after trimming.

Comment: For dotnet core 3.1 , below code needs to be written ::                                                                
modelBuilder.Model.SetMaxIdentifierLength(30);

Answer (score 0):

You get this error with Oracle database releases older than 12.2.0.1 because as of Oracle Database 12.2.0.1 identifiers can have 128 characters:

[12.2.0.1 doc says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/newft/new-features.html#GUID-64283AD6-0939-47B0-856E-5E9255D7246B)

> Long Identifiers
>
> The maximum length of identifiers is increased to 128 bytes for most identifiers, up from 30 bytes in previous releases.
>
> Providing longer identifiers gives customers greater flexibility in defining their naming schemes, such as longer and more expressive
>   table names. Having longer identifiers also enables object name
>   migration between databases with different character sets, such as
>   Thai to Unicode.

You could try to choose a more recent Oracle version such as 19c which has longer support than 12.1 or 12.2.0.1 or 18c.

Comment: Yes you are write about the length limit restriction but I have to do it with same oracle version due to company policy .